# What types of enemy attacks can shred armor?

Tags: xcom-2

Various types of enemies can shred armor with different attacks. Which abilities and attacks are those?

Answer (score 3):

This is a non-exhaustive list,

1. Grenade attacks (from any unit).
2. MEC basic rifle attacks, as well as their Micro Missile barrage.
3. Andromedon's Acid attack.

   - The Andromedon's rifle attack might also shred armor, but I haven't been able to confirm this yet.
4. The Sectopod's basic laser attack.

   - The Sectopod's AOE electricity and charged laser attacks might also shred armor, but I haven't been able to confirm yet.
5. > Avatars' basic Psionic Repeater attack.
6. Muton plasma shots

Comment: Corroborates the Muton plasma rifle shredding armor: http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Muton_%28XCOM_2%29

Comment: The Andromedon's rifle will shred 2 armour I believe.